# Updating Map View Controller with custom annotation depending on a specific variable in an array

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations

I have a map view controller that displays a certain icon depending a variable in an array.

For example, it shows blue if "blue", and red if "red".

Here are my Map View Controller functions:

```
//Creating the custom Annotation
struct Annotation {
var name: String?
var coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
var color: String?
}

//Func add annotations
 addAnnotations() {
 if self.annotationArray.count > 0 {
                        for i in 0..<self.annotationArray.count {
                    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                        annotation.title = self.annotationArray[i].name
                        annotation.coordinate = self.annotationArray[i].coordinates ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
                            
                        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                        }
     }

    //Determines the color
     func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "AnnotationView")
   

    if annotationView == nil {
        annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "AnnotationView")
    }
    annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
    if annotation === mapView.userLocation {
        return nil
    }
  
    for i in 0..<annotationArray.count {
        if annotationArray[I].color == "Blue" {
                annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Blue")?.transformToMapAnnotation()
            } else if annotationArray[I].color == "Red" {
            annotationView?.image = UIImage(named: "Red)?.transformToMapAnnotation()
 }
           return annotationView()
        } else {
        return annotationView()
   }

    }
```

I have a feeling it is because I return the annotation View as a single unit and am not matching each individual variable with its own unique annotation View. AKA there needs to be an array of annotationViews matching the other array?

Answer (score 1):

You don't loop through the annotations array in `viewForAnnotation`.  You need to use the annotation that is passed to that function to configure your annotation view.

Your problem is, then, that you don't know which element in the array corresponds to the annotation that has been passed.  One approach, if all of the annotations have unique names, would be to search through the annotation array looking for the match.  This isn't very efficient, particularly if you have a large number of annotations.

A better approach is to have the items in your array conform to `MKAnnotation`.  Unfortunately this means you need to make them a class rather than a struct.  Doing this would also require you to rename `coordinates` to `coordinate` and make it non-optional.

A compromise is to create a wrapper class

```
class MyAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let annotation: Annotation
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return annotation.coordinates ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    }
    var title: String? {
        return annotation.name
    }
    
    init(_ annotation: Annotation) {
        self.annotation = annotation
    }
    
}
```

Now, you need to supply instances of this annotation class:

```
func addAnnotations() {
   
    self.mapView.register(MKAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationWithReuseIdentifier:"AnnotationView")

    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotationArray.map { MyAnnotation($0) })
}
```

In `viewForAnnotation` you now need to determine if you are handling an instance of your annotation (through a conditional cast) and configure the view:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    
    guard let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation else {
        return nil
    }

    let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "AnnotationView", for: annotation)
   
    annotationView.canShowCallout = true
    
    let image = UIImage(named: annotation.color)?.transformToMapAnnotation()
    annotationView.image = image
    
    return annotationView
}
```